# Webpack is displaying empty pages, but files are being shown in terminal

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-dev-middleware

partially going insane right now. I have been trying to fix this problem for over a week, but still can not seem to fix it.

Currently I am trying to make a `React` application that utilizes `React-Router`, however I am NOT using `Redux` or `Flux`. I took the code from the [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit). I had experimented around with it a bit and all was working fine, but when I started changing things heavily is when I ran into issues.

**The problem is, when the pages loads NOTHING is being displayed.** When I say nothing I mean no `HTML`, `JS`, or `CSS`. All that is being displayed is the original base `HTML` file that consists of a `<header>` and `<body>` tag. When starting up the terminal I can see that the files are being loaded by `webpack`, here is what it looks like:

```
Server is now running at http://192.168.0.9:3000.
webpack built 928ca955f4efc3417ea7 in 11490ms
Hash: 928ca955f4efc3417ea7
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 11490ms
                                  Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   2abdf22181eb309fd513564971a12163.png    70.2 kB          [emitted]
   148e6bc6eabab75f3e18eddc2d99a10f.png      34 kB          [emitted]  
            app.928ca955f4efc3417ea7.js    1.04 MB       0  [emitted]  app
    1.charities.928ca955f4efc3417ea7.js    2.31 kB       1  [emitted]  charities
         vendor.928ca955f4efc3417ea7.js     405 kB       2  [emitted]  vendor
        app.928ca955f4efc3417ea7.js.map    1.29 MB       0  [emitted]  app
1.charities.928ca955f4efc3417ea7.js.map    3.53 kB       1  [emitted]  charities
     vendor.928ca955f4efc3417ea7.js.map     487 kB       2  [emitted]  vendor
                            favicon.ico    30.9 kB          [emitted]  
                             index.html  491 bytes          [emitted]    
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset    Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  565 kB       0        
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

When I load the page though, none of those items are being displayed. I thought `html-webpack-plugin` was suppose to inject the necessary files, but it is not doing so. I can not figure out why none of the necessary files are being loaded in to my HTML file. My webpack config is as so:

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import cssnano from 'cssnano'
import postcssNested from 'postcss-nested'
import postcssSimpleVars from 'postcss-simple-vars'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import config from '../config'

const paths = config.utils_paths
const {__PROD__} = config.globals

const webpackConfig = {
  name: 'client',
  target: 'web',
  devtool: config.compiler_devtool,
  resolve: {
    root: paths.client(),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  },
  module: {}
}

const APP_ENTRY_PATHS = [
  'babel-polyfill',
  paths.client('main.js'),
  `webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=${config.compiler_public_path}__webpack_hmr`
]

webpackConfig.entry = {
  app: APP_ENTRY_PATHS,
  vendor: config.compiler_vendor
}

webpackConfig.output = {
  filename: `[name].[${config.compiler_hash_type}].js`,
  path: paths.dist(),
  publicPath: config.compiler_public_path
}

webpackConfig.plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(config.globals),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: paths.client('index.html'),
    hash: false,
    favicon: paths.client('static/favicon.ico'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }
  }),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    names: ['vendor']
  })
]

if (__PROD__) {
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  )
}

webpackConfig.module.loaders = [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-1']
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json'
  }
]

const BASE_CSS_LOADER = 'css?sourceMap&-minimize'

const cssModulesRegex = new RegExp(
  `(${paths.client().replace(/[\^\$\.\*\+\-\?\=\!\:\|\\\/\(\)\[\]\{\}\,]/g, '\\$&')})`
)

const cssModulesLoader = [
  BASE_CSS_LOADER,
  'modules',
  'importLoaders=1',
  'localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
].join('&')

webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: cssModulesRegex,
  loaders: [
    'style',
    cssModulesLoader,
    'postcss'
  ]
})

webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: cssModulesRegex,
  loaders: [
    'style',
    BASE_CSS_LOADER,
    'postcss'
  ]
})

webpackConfig.postcss = [
  cssnano({
    autoprefixer: {
      add: true,
      remove: true,
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    },
    discardComments: {
      removeAll: true
    },
    discardUnused: false,
    mergeIdents: false,
    reduceIdents: false,
    safe: true,
    sourcemap: true
  }),
  postcssNested(),
  postcssSimpleVars({
    variables: function () {
      return require(paths.client('styles/variables'));
    }
  })
]

webpackConfig.module.loaders.push(
  { test: /\.woff(\?.*)?$/,  loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
  { test: /\.woff2(\?.*)?$/, loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2' },
  { test: /\.otf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=font/opentype' },
  { test: /\.ttf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
  { test: /\.eot(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]' },
  { test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
  { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,    loader: 'url?limit=8192' }
)

export default webpackConfig
```

Please help me figure out why my `index.html` is not being injected with ANY of the files needed. All that is being displayed is the original `index.html`. If you would like all of the files I am currently using you can view them [here](https://github.com/Phenominal/Phenominal). Thank you, please help!!

Comment: Do you only see nothing or there is really nothing? :) Does the browser's developer console show anything? Are there any errors there? Maybe your JS code just freezes up the browser?

Comment: Hello @EugZol, there is actually nothing there sadly! The only thing that is actually there is the plain old `index.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all that's being served is the fallback and static handlers you have configured in `server/main.js`

```
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use(fallback('index.html', { root }));
```

If you delete that the request hangs indefinitely. That's not the only necessary fix but that will hopefully help you get to the root of the problem.

Comment: Hello, so the root of the problem is that the requests are not being routed correctly, and therefor this is a server issue? I will try to test this tonight when I have time! Thank You

Comment: Yeah, sorry there's a lot going on in that codebase that I'm not super familiar with and I don't really have time to dig into it. Hopefully someone else is able to help more!

Comment: No, thank you! I am just glad you even looked :) Now I know that I probably need to focus on the routes.